# How to setText in JFrame w/o Action Performed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

I need to setText on a JLabel in a JFrame without input from the user. The setText code works fine when it is under jButtonActionPerformed but when under

```
public void FileName(){    
    jLabel2.removeAll();
    jLabel2.setText("Hello");
    jLabel2.validate();
}
```

the program runs fine but the JLabel does not change.

EDIT: I just want to know how to add a bit of text to a JLabel in a JFrame without any input from the user. Ignore the code above.

Comment: post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help, your question isn't clear.

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. Also note that random method calling rarely solves any problem :) No need for neither removeAll (why do you expect a label to have any children?) nor validate (as there were no children to remove)

Comment: My program is too long for an MCVE and I just want to know how to add a bit of text to a JLabel in a JFrame without any input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

To add text to a JLabel, use the `setText(String text)` method. It doesn't matter whether you call this from within an `actionPerformed` - you can call it anywhere and it will do what you expect.

If you're not seeing what you expect, then here are some possibilities:

1. The label you're setting the text on has not actually been added to the UI (or, you're using an instance of a JLabel that is different from the instance of the JLabel that is in the UI)
2. You are not calling your `FileName()` method (which should be renamed to start with a lowercase letter and preferably a verb - `displayFilename()` would be better)

Comment: Code that I used: http://imgur.com/jmp7T1L,cjdNTPt and result: http://imgur.com/jmp7T1L,cjdNTPt#1 there should be text in the red box (which is location of JLabel in GUI). I do not know why there is no text.

Comment: Where's the code that shows how you're adding jLabel2 to the GUI?

Comment: I used the JFrame GUI to create the jPanel2 so the code is automatically generated.

Comment: You still need to show us the code, otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `FileName()` method in the constructor of the `JFrame`.